# Installing sitecore item when it's in changeditems folder in .update package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We generate .update packages using Courier for our sitecore deployments. We have a baseline tag in github that marks current environment state and then we generate a folder of serialized items that denotes the environment state we want to create a package for.

So we end up with a package of addeditems, changeditems and deleteditems based on the contents of the two folders.

Sadly, our environments can fall out of sync so the baseline does not represent the true state of the environment. An example case:

- Baseline contains an item
- Item is changed in and package contains a changeditems reference in the .update package
- The environment we're installing the package on does not actually have the item that has been changed yet so nothing exists and therefore nothing can be changed

Is it possible to install an item if it does not exist even though the .update package contains a changeitems reference and no addeditems reference?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as if it is a changed item it only does an update - this is how the updateinstallationwizard works. Out of interest, why do the environments fall out of sync? Why are templates and layouts changing in your target environments?

Comment: You're right, the real problem is environment synchronisation. I was just curious about the package structure if anyone had built a fall back mechanism. Our integration environment is the one most liable to change. Items could be installed manually or missed on integration builds, which then get lost as a weekly deployment cycle is complete and the baseline tag is moved.